# FB get access token with permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, permissions, facebook-access-token

I'm using this method to get access token:

```
function _getToken(callback){
    FB.api('oauth/access_token', {
        client_id: fbSettings.client_id,
        client_secret: fbSettings.client_secret,
        grant_type: fbSettings.grant_type
    }, function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        if(res.error) {
            callback('error getting token: ', res.error);
            return;
        }
        callback(null, { token: res.access_token, expires: res.expires });
    });
}
```

Then i'm calling this query:

```
SELECT online_presence, name FROM user WHERE uid = ...
```

But response online presence is empty string because token i have generated does not have permission `user_online_presence`. How can i set this permission when generating token?

Comment: No idea where you found that code, but I can’t see it asking for that permission anywhere. __(And your app secret, which I suppose `fbSettings.client_secret` is, has no business ever being in client-side code!)__ Use `FB.login` for logging the user in and asking for permissions, that’s the officially documented way.

Comment: @CBroe It is not client side code, it's nodejs

Comment: Ah, OK, overlooked that. But anyway, what you are requesting there is an _app_ access token, whereas you want to get a user access token – and that has to be done by going through the login flow as described in the docs.

Comment: @CBroe you mean I can not get user access token only from server side?

Comment: Of course not, because it involves user interaction.

Comment: @CBroe that's sad. thanks very much

Comment: Well how else would the user grant permissions to your app – by visiting your server in its data center location …?